# Iterate through array in jumps

Tags: python, arrays, loops

I have an array from which I only need `value[1]`,`value[4]`,`value[7]`,`value[10]`,`value[13]` and `value[16]` (so basically every third value after the skipping `value[0]`).

I need to do an equation with each of these values and return each answer into an array. The function I've written is, however, not making jumps of 3 and instead using every value. How would I fix this?

```
popt=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18] #I only want to use popt[1],popt[4],popt[7] etc. 

def d(popt):
  dvalues=[]
  i=1
  for i in range(0, len(popt)//3):
      d=wavelength()/(2 * math.sin(math.radians(popt[i] / 2)))
      dvalues.append(d)
      I+=3
  return(dvalues)
print(d(popt))
```

Comment: Have a look at something like popt3 = popt[::3] to use every third item in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

```
for i in range(1, len(popt), 3):
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach which uses:

- [list comprehension](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-list-comprehensions-in-python-3) for the calculation
- [slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/6340496) to create your `popt` list.

#### Sample Code:

```
import math

def d(popt):
    # I don't have your `wavelength()` function, so have used 1. 
    vals = [1 / (2 * math.sin(math.radians(i / 2))) for i in popt]
    return vals

# Create a list of every 3 numbers from 1-18. 
popt = [i for i in range(1, 18)][::3]
output = d(popt)
```

#### Output:

```
# Using 1, rather than your wavelength() function.
[57.296506740065155,
 14.326854173921912,
 8.19020411969913,
 5.736856622834928,
 4.416835735998784,
 3.5926482671638595]
```